# AMP analytics - track clicks from CSS class name

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I have implemented tracking on my first AMP site and global tracking is working well but I haven't found a solution to track clicks on specific CSS classes.

For unique selectors like id="my_unique_name", I use the following:

```
 "price click": 
            {
                "on": "click",
                "selector": "#my_unique_name",
                "request": "event",
                "vars": 
                    {
                        "eventCategory": "Activity",
                        "eventAction": "Price button"
                    }                   

            }
```

This works fine.

Now if I try to capture clicks on something like this: class="my_class" it doesn't work. I have tried the following possibilities:

```
"selector": "div.my_class"
"selector": ".my_class"
"selector": "my_class"
```

Is there a way to track clicks based on CSS classes?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: look here to see how google does it: https://www.ampproject.org/

Comment: Maybe is tag manager a solution for you. It brings CSS selector as a variable to use.

Comment: @JayGray Thanks but that's where I have been looking for the answer, also on ampbyexample.com but none of the examples are using classes :-(

Comment: @Lovntola Thanks but I don't use a tag manager